# Inheriting a class that has the same constructor but different/similar prototypes

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a constructor:

```
function Constructor(input) {
  this.input = input
}

Constructor.prototype.method = function() {
  console.log('a')
}
```

But I want to make another class using a copy of the constructor, but changing the prototypes.

```
function Constructor2(input) {
  this.input = input
}

Constructor2.prototype.method = function() {
  console.log('b')
}
```

I don't want to redefine the constructor. How would you do this? Ideally it would be something as simple as:

```
var Constructor2 = inherits(Constructor)
Constructor2.prototype.method = // overwrite the inherited `method()`
```

Comment: You can't do that in same scope. means you can't have two different function with same name

Comment: i see two different functions with two different names

Comment: This is confusing. Why do you want to do this in the first place.

Comment: because i have similar classes with a few different methods

Comment: `var constructor2 = new Constructor();` Then `constructor2.method = function(){console.log('overridden method')}`

Comment: @JonathanOng Constructor2 is not a name of function for line var Constructor2 = inherits(Constructor).

Comment: `Constructor2` is a copy of `Constructor`. I don't get what's confusing about that. Or maybe I just don't understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var inherits = function(childCtor, parentCtor) {
  /** @constructor */
  function tempCtor() {};
  tempCtor.prototype = parentCtor.prototype;
  childCtor.superClass_ = parentCtor.prototype;
  childCtor.prototype = new tempCtor();
  /** @override */
  childCtor.prototype.constructor = childCtor;
};



// How to use it:

var Constructor1 = function() {
//add all your methods, variables etc
};

Constructor1.prototype.myMethod = function() {
};

var Contructor2 = function() {
Contructor1.call(this); // Call the super class constructor
};
inherits(Contstructor2, Constructor1);
// Constructor2 now inherits from Constructor1
// override, add methods variables etc, whatever you need.

// Have fun!
```

Comment: Yup, this is what I've decided to do (look at my answer). Difference being I use `.apply(this, arguments)` since my constructor has arguments, and I put `function() {Constructor1.call}` inside `inherits` for this specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, much easier just to use `apply`:

```
function newConstructor(Super) {
  function Construct() {
    Super.apply(this, arguments)
  }

  require('util').inherits(Construct, Super)

  return Construct
}
```

Comment: So all you want is to use the same constructor, but not the same prototype?

Comment: Just add the property at the instance level.

Comment: Changing the property at the instance level !== changing the property at the constructor level

Comment: Can you show a concrete example ? What you're saying doesn't make much sense in the context given.

Comment: `function Animal(attributes) { _.defaults(this, attributes) }`, `function Cat(attributes) { _.defaults(this, attributes) }`. Animal and Cat have the same constructors, but they might have different movements. You don't want to do `var cat = new Animal(attributes)`, `cat.move = function() ...` every time you make a new cat. that's retarded.

Comment: lol Jonathan, why didn't you give that example to start with ? You would have gotten many more responses.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nasty-ish solution:

```
function Constructor1(input) {
  this.input = input;
}

Constructor1.prototype.method = function() {
  console.log('a');
}

// be careful here: evals the string value of Constructor1 with references to "Constructor1" changed to "Constructor2"
eval(Constructor1.toString().replace("Constructor1", "Constructor2"));

Constructor2.prototype.method = function() {
  console.log('b');
}

var c1 = new Constructor1(1);
var c2 = new Constructor2(2);
console.log(c1.constructor === c2.constructor) // true

c1.method() // a
c2.method() // b
```