# Expose a computable globally

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I would like to expose a computable globally in knockout.js (without promoting to the global javascript scope), for example:

```html
<span data-binding="text: resource('test/resources', 'myresource')"></span>
```

Alternatively have some binding that passes a new value to the parent value:

```html
<span data-binding="text: {resource: res: 'test/resources', name: 'myresource'}"></span>
```

Unfortunately my exhaustive search hasn't turned anything up. Is this at all possible?

**note:** I know I can add this to the `ViewModel`, but this wouldn't deal with nested objects, and `$root.resource` isn't DRY enough for my standards. I could also use inheritance, but I want to avoid that *if possible*. Essentially what I am trying to do is extend the 'expressions' in ko.

Comment: I don't understand your question completely. Could you provide a snippet of JavaScript in a fiddle? Code doesn't have to run, just so I can see what's going on. Also, would a custom binding be sufficient?

Comment: @Anzeo there you go: http://jsfiddle.net/a95G9/1/ - I don't mind a binding if I can use it with other bindings (see the second example).

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it, see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this with a custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.resource = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor){
        // Do here whathever you'd like to do with the resource

    }
};
```

You can use this custom binding like standard KO bindings, like:

```
<div data-bind="resource: myResource"></div>
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anzeo/a95G9/2/) here.

**EDIT** updated my fiddle according to the new info you provided, here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anzeo/a95G9/3/)

Comment: Thanks Anzeo, the problem is this: `element.innerHTML =`. I am wondering if it's possible to pass my binding into another one (see the second example in the body of my question). So e.g. we get both `text: {resource: res}` and `attr: {src: {resource: res}}`.

Comment: You want to call the text binding from within your custom binding?

Comment: Not necessarily only text, any binding. So either have any binding call my one (preferable) or maybe something like `resource: { res: res, bind: text}`.

Comment: Having any binding call your one is going to require editing the KO framework code, not sure you want that. The other option isn't that hard. I'll edit my answer with the updated fiddle in a min

Comment: One note though, if you're thinking about using this all over your application, you might want to rethink what you're doing

Comment: this is what I am doing: https://github.com/jcdickinson/nodebug/blob/master/app/templates/ui/body.htm#L64 . Keep in mind that plugins could create menus, with their own resources. Hence the requirement.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21398/discussion-between-anzeo-and-jonathan-dickinson)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I would either go for inheritance, using [this pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982850/inheriting-a-class-that-has-the-same-constructor-but-different-similar-prototype/12983130#12983130), or simply alias the namespace from ko and alter it(basically copy the namespace from ko to some object and play around with it until you achieve the desired functionality).

Comment: So does adding functions to ko add them to the 'expression evaluation'? I don't mind altering ko directly, I just want to expose functions to bindings.

Comment: These solutions are way too heavy for something simple as what the OP's asking